# What is the pdf of the integral of a gaussian process and of the ratio of two gaussian variables?

Tags: density-function, gaussian-process, integral, ratio

I need to evaluate the moment functions of a zero mean gaussian process that constitutes the mathematical model of the seismic ground acceleration during an earthquake.

[image]

Comment: Please don't paste images of your question; use mathjax and enter the text.  It affects the ability of some vision-impaired people to read the question.